# I am trying to implement paging using mysql limit

Tags: mysql, node.js, dql

If you select that category, I want to show only 9 products in that category per page. So I tried using LIMIT OFFSET as below, but it doesn't work.

Is there any other way? I need help.

```
const readCategory = async (categoryId, page) => {
  const categoryProducts = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT c.name AS category, c.level AS categoryDepth,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          "name", p.name, 
          "description", p.description,
          "priceOrigin", p.price
        )
      ) AS products
    FROM products p
    JOIN category c ON c.id = p.category_id
    WHERE p.category_id = ?
    GROUP BY p.category_id
    LIMIT (?-1)*9, 9`,
    [categoryId, page]
  );
  return categoryProducts;
};
```

The number in front of (1-1) of LIMIT is a number indicating a page, and when that number is received as a query, it was my intention to make it possible to search from the product calculated as -1.

If you do this, you will get the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1-1)*9, 9' at line 21

---

I have 3 files and I tried again like this:

```
//controller.js
const readCategory = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { categoryId, page } = req.query;
    const categoryProducts = await productsService.readCategory(categoryId, page);
    res.status(200).json({ data: categoryProducts });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: 'ERROR' });
  }
};

//service.js
const readCategory = async (categoryId, page) => {
  const products = await productsDao.readCategory(categoryId, page);

  products.map(data => {
    data.products = JSON.parse(data.products);
  });

  return products;
};

//DAO.js
const readCategory = async (categoryId, page) => {
  const categoryProducts = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT c.name AS category, c.level AS categoryDepth,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          "name", p.name, 
          "description", p.description,
          "priceOrigin", p.price
        )
      ) AS products
    FROM products p
    JOIN category c ON c.id = p.category_id
    WHERE p.category_id = ?
    GROUP BY p.category_id
    LIMIT ?, 9`,
    [categoryId, (page-1)*9]
  );
  return categoryProducts;
};
```

After that, as a postman, I tried to send a query with ?categoryId=9&page=1 after the url, but all products were searched inside "products". I want only 9 products to be viewed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work". What error do you get?

Comment: I've added a description of what error I'm getting.

Comment: You should calculate the offset at the application level and then provide it as an integer value to the query'

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Could you please show me the code?

Comment: Can you share the code that creates this query?

Comment: Added code to generate query.

Comment: What if you replace the page calculation with just a hardcode value? Maybe it's just not possible to have a calculation in your LIMIT clause.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/select.html says: **"LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants..."** or parameters or local variables in stored routines. But not expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem with this.
JSON_ARRAYAGG, GROUP BY
After removing these, I confirmed that LIMIT was working fine.

However, I couldn't figure out why JSON_ARRAYAGG, GROUP BY and LIMIT are not connected.

If anyone knows, I would appreciate it if you could share your knowledge.

Comment: https://dncrews.com/limit-and-offset-can-work-with-join-f03327fa2ad3

Comment: `limit` and `offset` keyword should do the work for paging.  Even possibly, something like datatable.net.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support expressions with LIMIT, so you have to perform the calculation in your application code:

```
…
LIMIT ?, 9`,
[categoryId, (page - 1) * 9]
```

Comment: After writing as you said, if you check ?categoryId=9&page=1 , it will return all data, not just 9.

Comment: You're not showing any code on how you retrieve `categoryId` and `page`, so I have no idea why that is. There's nothing inherently wrong with my answer, I tested it and it will return (at most) 9 results, as expected. It could be that your query itself isn't working properly, but I assume you checked that before posting a question here.

Comment: It seems I am doing something wrong. But I don't know the cause. I've posted the code I tried the way you said. what am i doing wrong??

Comment: You need to post the code where you call the `readCategory` function. Are you sure that `categoryId` and `page` are actually valid?

Comment: I added all the code that calls the function. No problems were found elsewhere. 

Comment: So when you run the hardcoded query from the MySQL command line tool (or another database query tool) it works as expected?

Comment: yes everything else works as expected.

Comment: I figured out the problem with this!
I removed JSON_ARRAYAGG and GROUP BY and got the result I wanted.

But I still don't know why JSON_ARRAYAGG, GROUP BY and LIMIT are not concatenated.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MySQL doesn't allow expressions in the `limit` clause. You could instead calculate them on the Node.js side though:

```js
const readCategory = async (categoryId, page) => {
  const categoryProducts = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT c.name AS category, c.level AS categoryDepth,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          "name", p.name, 
          "description", p.description,
          "priceOrigin", p.price
        )
      ) AS products
    FROM products p
    JOIN category c ON c.id = p.category_id
    WHERE p.category_id = ?
    GROUP BY p.category_id
    LIMIT ?, 9`,
    [categoryId, (page - 1) * 9]
  );
  return categoryProducts;
};
```

Side note: You'd probably want to add an `order by` clause to your query so it doesn't rely on some arbitrary order returned by the database.

Comment: After writing as you said, if you check ?categoryId=9&page=1 , it will return all data, not just 9.